# After copying with INSERT...SELECT, I have more records than before

Tags: mysql

I have a strange occurance: I copied ~4.7m records from one table to another in MySQL 5.6.14, using INSERT INTO tabl1 (col1,...) SELECT (col2...) FROM tbl2... and I have more records than before. 640 to be exact.

I checked by doing a select count(*) on both tables, subtracting the new table from the old table (which gave me the -640).

Any ideas? I'd like to know where the extra 640 records came from.

Both are InnoDB; the old table is latin charset, the new is utf8. Doubt that's part of the equation, but maybe someone with much more exp with MySQL would know.

SQL statement example:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) SELECT (`colA`,`colB`,`colC`) FROM `table2`;
```

The table receiving records is new, and has 0 records in it, and never had records in it. Also, it's not a production environment, so nothing should be adding records to it except this 1 statement.

Comment: Please show the full statement you used. And is the database in active use? Could someone have deleted records since you ran the INSERT?

Comment: If you already had data in the previous table before inserting then you will have more data. If you want them to be exact then you must do a truncate on the table first before inserting. Unless your sql statement is giving you duplicate data then you need to check your sql statemetn. Highlight your select statement first and run it to see the results and if it correct then all you need to do is truncate the table before inserting

Comment: I added this to the question, but the table receiving records is completely new, including the schema. It's also not a production env, so there are no other transactions other than this 1 statement. Finally, the count from the old table is less than the count from the new table (after the inserts).

Comment: I don't see why that would give you more rows than the other table. Do you have a trigger/procedure on that table that is geenrating dummy rows or something?

Comment: No triggers/procedures.

Comment: this is mysql right?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. First remove the table if it exists already in the database. This way you know for sure that `tabl1` won't have any extra data.

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabl1`;
2. Recreate the table to be copied which will be `tabl2` using a `create table` statement to copy everything from `tabl2` into `tabl1` as follows:

   CREATE TABLE `tabl1` SELECT * FROM `tabl2

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Its already explained in the comments section above but sure.

Comment: Comments are temporary beasts and the answers need to be complete, otherwise they can be voted for deletion.  Now that it is looking better, I have upvoted it.

Comment: Oh ok, i understand. Thanks